# Error: Unknown constructor 'PickListClass.PickListClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller)

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="PickListClass">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >            
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/><br/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!Account.Name}" />
            <apex:selectList value="{!Rating}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!RatingOptions}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class PickListClass{
     public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}
    public void PickListClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        stdCntrlr = controller;
    }

    public String Rating{get; set;}
    public List<String> selectedCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> getRatingOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> RatingOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        RatingOptions.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        RatingOptions.add(new SelectOption('Hot','Hot'));
        RatingOptions.add(new SelectOption('Warm','Warm'));
        RatingOptions.add(new SelectOption('Cold','Cold'));

        return RatingOptions;
    }



}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on how to create a custom controller to define the constructor? You may also want to think about your naming since there may already be a picklist class for standard visualforce. I know there's a dynamicpicklist class found in the apex docs..

Answer (score 3):

Constructors do not have a return type.

**Incorrect**

```
public class PickListClass{
    public void PickListClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    //     ^^^^
    {
        // not a constructor
    }
}
```

**Correct**

```
public class PickListClass{
    public PickListClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // now it is a constructor
    }
}
```